# Rails : Why my first page does not show? (routing error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use *scaffold* to create my first MVC in Rails 3.1

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

I deleted the *public/index.html* file

Then I added following code in *config/routes.rb*

```
root :to => 'post#index'
```

But when I start the server with `rails s`, there is an error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PostController):
```

Why? why it does not render the `posts/index.html.erb` but throw the error?

Comment: Solved. It is my typo, I should use posts#index in the routes.rb file instead of post#index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It created `PostsController`, not `PostController`. It's plural.

Change your routes.rb file to this: `root :to => 'posts#index'`

EDIT: I didn't see the OP's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run rake db:migrate first?

Comment: Yes, I did that first, then I use scaffolder with --skip option to skip the existing files